# Cannot get my JS function to execute on multiple products

Tags: javascript, html, dom, bootstrap-4

I'm new to Javascript.

You can see the button. I want to open a 'window' over the top. Works for product 1 (chili oil). This is a kind of timeline, where the user hovers (see item title/price), clicks down (small black border), then mouseUp (which displays the window).

I am trying to figure out why it doesn't work on product 2. The function was in the first instance, calling the button / divs with their IDs. I changed the actual button to calling the class .btn, and left the div as id zoom.

Eventually I want to open the div you see from product 1 click, and fill it with the item description stored in the javascript object, depending on what item was clicked. Thought it was the most efficient way of doing this if we end up with 100s of products on the site, but I'm sure there may be a better way (any suggestions?).

HTML

```
            <div class="liqueursContainer">
            <!--Product 1-->
            <div class="product" style="border-bottom: 0px;">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <img src="images/chillioil.jpg" class="image" alt="Chili Oil">
                    <div class="middle">
                        <div><p class="abt-product-desc-sm" id="pr-desc-clk1">
                            <a onmousedown="prMouseDown()" onmouseup="prMouseUp()" id="product-zoom" class="btn btn-default">Chili&nbsp;Oil<br>35cl<br>
                            £8.99</a>
                        </p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="add-cart cart1" href="#"><p class="cart-but-txt">Add to Cart</p></a>
            </div>
            <!--Product 2-->
            <div class="product" style="border-bottom: 0px;">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <img src="images/raspratafia.jpg" class="image" alt="Raspberry Ratafia">
                    <div class="middle">
                        <div><p class="abt-product-desc-sm" id="pr-desc-clk2" style="left: -55px; top: -78px;">
                            <a onmousedown="prMouseDown()" onmouseup="prMouseUp()" id="product-zoom" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgb(78, 78, 78); color: white">Raspberry<br>Ratafia<br>50cl<br>
                            £15.99</a>
                        </p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="add-cart cart2" href="#"><p class="cart-but-txt">Add to Cart</p></a>
            </div>
         </div>

        <div id="zoom" class="container d-none"> 
            <p></p>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
    .middle {
transition: .5s ease;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
text-align: center;
opacity: 0;
margin-bottom: 150px;
}
.product {
width: 45%;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
text-align: right;
align-items: center;
border-bottom: 2px solid #660000;
display: flex;
}
.product {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.liqueursContainer {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
margin-top: 25px;
}
#product-zoom {
background-color: azure;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1.5;
font-size: 17px;
color: black;
height: 85px;
top: -150px;
opacity: 0.5;
}
.abt-product-desc-sm {
position: relative;
top: -70px;
left: -50px;
color: rgb(133, 133, 133);
font-weight: 550;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
}
#zoom {
position: relative; 
width: 75%;
background-color: white;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 500px;
top: -700px;
border-radius: 15px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Javascript

```
                const button = document.querySelector('.btn');           // This is the main script to view the div

            button.addEventListener('click', function() {                  
                const zoom = document.getElementById('zoom');
                
                if (zoom.classList.contains('d-none')) {             // Using a bootstrap operation to hide/show div with 'd-none' class
                    zoom.classList.remove('d-none');
                    
                } else {
                    zoom.classList.add('d-none');     
                }
                                
            });

            function prMouseDown() {
                document.getElementById("pr-desc-clk1").style.border = "1px solid black";     //This is an attempt to get the black border around each products click
                document.getElementById("pr-desc-clk1").style.borderRadius = "3px";           // But I haven't yet worked out how to do this from a couple of lines (using a class did not seem to work)
                 
                document.getElementById("pr-desc-clk2").style.border = "1px solid black";
                document.getElementById("pr-desc-clk2").style.borderRadius = "3px";
                document.getElementById("pr-desc-clk2").style.left = "-56px";
```

Comment: I feel I may be jumping the gun a little bit and need to follow more tutorials before I start modifying the DOM haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, `document.querySelector` will return only first element. So the event will be binded for the first one only.

You **should** use **document.querySelectorAll** to fetch more than one elements. It will return `Array nodes[]`, Then have to iterate the array to deal with single node.

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
  
  for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {                  
        const zoom = document.getElementById('zoom');
                
        if (zoom.classList.contains('d-none')) {
            zoom.classList.remove('d-none');
        } else {
            zoom.classList.add('d-none');     
        }
                                
    });
  }
```

Comment: It works thank you!! It was that simple :) I will get back to the tutorials and courses me thinks hahaha